# How do I make my A-Frame scene accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility, aframe, webvr

So I have my A-Frame scene with some links in it, but as far as I'm aware the `<canvas>` element isn't really accessible - how can I make my scene usable for all users?

The method I'm aware of is to put accessible HTML children to the `<canvas>`, but as the A-Frame canvas is created dynamically, so I'm not sure on how to do this. My initial guesses at ignorance are:

1. A-Frame has a built-in accessiblility component that I'm not aware of
2. There's a way to tell A-Frame to use a specific `<canvas>` element that I'm not aware of.
3. Something wild that I can't even think of right now

Any guidance on this would be grand, so thanks in advance!

-p

Answer (score 1):

There's not too much work in accessibility in VR yet. But you could make a set of accessibility components thought that that you get just plug into any entity that might do a text-to-speech thing, make more reliance on sound and haptics.

e.g. you might make a component that talks when hovered on with controller or touched (`<a-entity a11y="message: This is a box.">`). Or start to rumble haptics based on proximity to an interactable object.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I have a project for the easter weekend!